# Using Contact Forms to Send Private Information

Tags: forms, security, contact

I am working on a site for a Doctors Office who wants to use a contact form to send information about their patients to other offices....I was going to use contact form 7 but I'm wondering if there is a security issue with sending private information.  Do you have any suggestions on the best forms to use for sending personal information securely?  Maybe they should get an SSL?  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts are to SSL the entire site due to the nature of the project.

There are also things you can do to forms to make them safer, when recently reading the Stripe payment gateway documentation they suggest not adding a `name` attribute to the fields in the form until the final second with some javascript.

SSL and no mixed content loading (which is making sure every asset is loaded over SSL too) should be sufficient though.